# install apcu PHP extension in azure webapp linux container

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, apcu

I'm trying to start existing php application in azure App Service.
Application is using apcu extension.
I'm trying to istall extension to the app service.
I connect via ssh and try to install the extension via

```
pecl install apcu
```

But I'm getting following error:

```
creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
configure: patching config.h.in
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
running: make
/bin/bash /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdX8M2c/apcu-5.1.19/libtool --mode=compile cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/apcu -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdX8M2c/a
pcu-5.1.19/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdX8M2c/apcu-5.1.19/main -I/tmp/pear/temp/apcu -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/u
sr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc.c -o apc.lo
 cc -D_GNU_SOURCE -DZEND_ENABLE_STATIC_TSRMLS_CACHE=1 -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/apcu -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdX8M2c/apcu-5.1.19/include -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootdX8M2c/apcu-5.1.19/main -I/tmp
/pear/temp/apcu -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g
 -O2 -c /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/apc.o
In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc.c:32:
/tmp/pear/temp/apcu/apc.h:64:10: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
 #include <config.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:194: apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in php 7.4 version. I switch it to `7.2` and `7.3`, and it works for me.

**Tips**

*If you insist on using version 7.4, you can try to install apcu and then switch the version back to 7.4. I haven't tested this solution with a project, it's just an alternative solution, I hope it helps you.*

[You can raise a support ticket to confirm this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Change the php version to `7.2` or `7.3` first,

**and run command `pecl install apcu` .**
it works for me.

**Step 1. Change php version.**

[image]

**Step 2. Open SSH.**

[image]

**Step 3. Run command `pecl install apcu`**

[image]
[image]